# Android - Summing user input edittext numbers using a for loop

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a situation as shown in this pic here: [User enters quantity to cart on Add To Cart button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aODE7.png)

Every time a user adds an item to the cart, I want to store quantity number in an arraylist(or list) and display quantity on ITEMS textview. If user adds another item, then arraylist(one with first quantity) should be increased by second quantity and display sum in ITEMS textview, essentially computing the sum of the quantities added.

So, I tried using a for loop,

```
String quantity_temp = String.valueOf(quantityPicker_Npkr.getText().toString());
int quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantity_temp);    


int total = 0;
//declare and initialize an arraylist;

for (int i = 1; i < //declaredArralist.size(); i++) {

    total = total + quantity;
    itemNo_txt.setText("  " + total);
 }
```

The challenge I am having is that the above `for loop` is not consistent, in one instance, it adds correctly, then in the next, it increments differently. How do I go about this.

Be gentle, am new to android. My code is no perfect

Comment: I don't understand the problem. ArrayList is dynamic by default

Comment: ArrayList in java is always dynamic in terms of size.

Comment: my bad, array and arraylist two different things. You guys are right.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will address your problem. You would want to set text after the loop.

```
ArrayList<Integer> quantityList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

//This code has to repeat each time the customer enters an item to a card.
//Use it inside a loop or in case of a button click event, run this code.

String quantity_temp = String.valueOf(quantityPicker_Npkr.getText().toString());
int quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantity_temp);
quantityList.add(quantity);

//End of repeating code

//For the display total part
int total = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < quantityList.size(); i++) {
   total = total + quantity;       
}

itemNo_txt.setText("  " + total);
```

Comment: umhm negative, its printing 0 now when I press Add to Cart button

Comment: Yes it is.Since I have assigned 0 to quantity and I am adding only that to arraylist, output will be 0.You should add items to the ArrayList in the line I have commented.

quantityList.add(quantity);

Comment: thats the thing, my quantity is coming with an int from edittext and the same time, you setting quantity be equal to 0 again??

String quantity_temp = String.valueOf(quantityPicker_Npkr.getText().toString());
int quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantity_temp);

Comment: Yes. My mistake there. No need to assign that.

Comment: how about 

quantityList.add(quantity + value from edittext); 

lol okay am not making sense right now

Comment: Since I do not know the complete code, I do not know what is the best way to do it. :)  But one thing for sure is the for loop should run only after you have added everything to the arraylist.

Comment: I think problem is coming from

for (int i = 1; i < quantityList.size(); i++)

Comment: Yes it should be like (int i=0; i < quantityList.size(); i++)

Comment: great, now we going somewhere, I changed it to 0 and its working but for the entered quantity only. Meaning if I enter 3, it will be printed. Then if I enter 7, the 3 is replaced with 7. Its not adding them up

Comment: That is because you are only adding one item.If you want to add multiple, then you have to use a loop. For an example,

for(int x=0;x<10;x++){
    quantityList.add(quantity);
}

.Each time the loop runs you can provide a new value for quantity. May be from a function that returns a value. Hope now its clear :)

Comment: umhm okay, so you saying I should have two for loops? Am sorry Kalhara if am becoming too much. I just need some help ey

`int total = 0;
                    ArrayList<Integer> quantityList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for(int x=0;x<10;x++){
                        quantityList.add(quantity);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < quantityList.size(); i++) {
                        total = total + quantity;
                    }

                    itemNo_txt.setText("  " + total);`

Comment: Simply put its like this.Lets say user add something to card. Try to create a function that will add that quantity to your arrayList.So in that function, first two lines of your original code and quantityList.add(quantity); will have to be there.I am assuming user adding something is a button click event or user input. So in such a event you pass that input and the defined arraylist as a parameter to the function. eg : public void addItemToArrayList(int input,ArrayList<Integer>  quantityList){//Code}. I hope it helps.If you find this helpful please accept the answer :)

Comment: Edited the code to further help you understand it. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create ArrayList for this

```
ArrayList<YourItemClass> items = new ArrayList<YourItemClass>();

items.add(new YourItemClass(...));
items.add(new YourItemClass(...));
```

and to retrieve the data you can iterate over it

```
for (YourItemClass item : items) {
   //use your item to display
}
```

If you only want to use String then YourItemClass can be String like this

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

items.add(new String(...));
items.add(new String(...));
```

and to retrieve the strings you can iterate over it

```
for (String item : items) {
   //use your item string to display
}
```

Comment: umhm @Shriyansh that sounds like Greek to me but thanks, let me try it out